# howto push and promote docker image by Jenkins with Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

Currently we are using Jenkins to build and push docker images to Artifactory by docker native commands:

```
docker build -t "my_artificatory_repo/the_image:1.0.0" .
docker push "my_artificatory_repo/the_image:1.0.0"
```

but it prevents us from using an Artifactory plugin for Jenkins to promote images by a
`rtAddInteractivePromotion`  for example.

Is there a way to push docker images using Artifactory plugin so users could release images later just by clicking "promote" in Jenkins build UI?

What is the BKM using Artifactory-Jenkins to build and release docker images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Github example [JenkinsFile](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/docker-pull-example/Jenkinsfile) would help in setting up the JFrog Artifactory plugin.
You can also refer to this [wiki](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/declarative-pipeline-syntax#:%7E:text=to%20the%20setup%20instructions.-,Working%20with%20Docker%20Daemon%20Directly,-The%20Jenkins%20Artifactory%20Plugin%20supports) on setting up declarative script for Docker.

Comment: thanks, the push stage works fine. However, the promotion doesn't allow user to tag the image differently - it's only proposing pushing to another repo, which is not the best way release docker images.

Comment: @DimaKreisserman
were you able to find a solution for Atrifactory?
trying to find similar solution, using this promote process [using the api](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/promote-docker-images)
but getting error 500 with message: "Destination and source are the same. Promotion aborted"

i cannot understand what is the motivation of blocking the promote in the same repo...